# Drive NAME does not show up when viewing in Explorer but does in Disk Management

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-management, label

### Issue:

When I have a drive attached to my PC (non-USB) it shows up fine in disk management and shows up fine when checking under "Computer" (where you see all your drives, and I can also use the drive with absolutely no issues.  The problem is the drive label.  Even though the label is set the drive is displayed in "Computer" as if it has no label.  As seen in the image below, it shows up fine in disk manager (area 1) and in (area 2).  But when opening up "Computer" it will not show the label correctly in (area 3) or (area 4)!

[image]

### More Info:

I have seen this issue happen before and usually a reboot tends to fix the issue.  Before when it has happened to me it had to do with a thumb drive and this time it is a hard drive.  I know some times it has to do with a hidden file on the disk/drive but that is not the case this time.  There are no hidden FILES on the root of the drive.

Ideas?

Comment: Looks like the drive is shared. Try renaming the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is from 2 years ago but still someone can find the answer useful.

So, this happened to me 1 week ago and just now I've fixed it.
The only thing you have to do is give SYSTEM full permissions on the entire drive. Apply and then reboot and done.

Better don't delete SYSTEM's permissions because it can cause problems with .msi installers aswell, they will show "error reading from file", but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

In my case on win 7 it was sufficient to restart Explorer.  Note that includes the Explorer process that shows the desktop.  System already had full control.

Here's one easy way to do that:  https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/75938-restart-explorer-exe-easy-way.html

In response to comments, here is what they recommend:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

In addition, they offer a way to add that to the explorer context menu, which I omit here since it is not directly relevant to the question.

Comment: This is simple and it works well

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this, by using [**USB Drive Letter Manager (USBDLM)**](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) (works on all Windows versions).

I was using this tool to [assign a consistent driver letter for each time I insert the same external usb hard drive](https://superuser.com/a/108188/35525).
And then I realised that it can also assign the labels, so that it doesn't give the generic label for all my drives.

I set it up for example:

```
[DriveLetters]
DeviceID=3489230498324098
Letter=G
DefaultLabel=Finally a name
```

Read more in the help section on Default Labels:
https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#defaultletters