# How to prevent Windows assigning automatic drive letters?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

For some reasons, sometimes i have to disconnect on of my internal hard drives,  problem is every time i re-attach drive, Windows assign wrong letters to partitions and this make all program installations of partitions false. (probably because of DVD drive letter moving to beginning of list)

Is there anyway to set STABLE letters to each partition?

Comment: You shouldn't be disconnecting drives. When you do this Windows is going to reorder the assigned drive letters. Solve the problem why you have to keep disconnecting an "internal" drive - that's not right. Also, you didn't specify which version of Windows you have.

Comment: @Appleoddity You are right, i need this for testing some infected drives, anyway I'll change this method soon. i added windows version in tags.

Comment: Put the infected drives in a caddy and attach through USB, your internal drives will stay connected and keep the same drive letter.

Comment: In general, if you have a known-infected HD, it's better to boot to an OS less susceptible to infection, and connect the trouble HD outside of the box. 
  Some malware can transmit just by mounting a drive into a Windows PC.  I use an external USB docking station for touch-and-go data transfers.  Same idea as an enclosure, but easier to get in/out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign permanent drive letters to removable USB hard drives](https://superuser.com/questions/108186/how-to-assign-permanent-drive-letters-to-removable-usb-hard-drives)

Answer (score 1):

Disk Management is your friend (`diskmgmt.msc`)

Right-click any partition in the list of known volumes, and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths." Click "Change," then select a drive letter. These changes should persist as the drive is disconnected/reconnected.